# Is there a way to toggle/fix a menu while scrolling?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I want to build a Windows Forms App that has a menu (several labels) on it's left side which is toggled. On the right side there should be some columns i can scroll through. Jst like Excel with it's fixed rownumbers.

Is there a way to do this? Preferably an easy one.[image: Something like this.]

Comment: I didn't even know winforms was still being used.

Comment: There are several solutions for that. Dock left panel to Left, Dock right panel to Fill. Left panel is not scrollable, right panel is scrollable. You can also use SplitContainer. You can also use TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @SILENT you mean i should switch to WPF? I don't really need the fancy looks, it just needs to work properly.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Ok, i will take a look at that.

Comment: Using a SplitContainer is an ideal solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use two panels to make the form like the picture you provided.

The following code is a code example and you can refer to it.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ScrollBar hScrollBar1 = new HScrollBar();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            panel2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            hScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            hScrollBar1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(hScroller_Scroll);
            panel2.Controls.Add(hScrollBar1);
            panel2.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
            panel2.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void hScroller_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.HorizontalScroll.Value = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
```

The specific result:
[image]